# failed compile command runs on exit, prevents exit – how to track down?

Tags: hooks, compilation, quitting, exit

I'm on a new system (Amazon Linux 2015.9), and my emacs config seems to not like the stock install (Emacs 24.3.1) or vice-versa.

When I do `C-x C-c` it runs `save-buffers-kill-terminal`.

But this fails, and writes `Wrong type argument: listp, "make -k "` to the minibuffer.

I have determined that whatever value I set for `compile-command` will appear in the message.  For example, I can make emacs fail to exit with the message `Wrong type argument: listp, "foobar "` or `Wrong type argument: listp, ""`.

But I can't figure out what it causing a compile to run on exit or how to shut it off.

Is there a hook that lives somewhere?  Does anyone have any ideas for tracking this down?

At the moment I can only quit by backgrounding the process and doing `kill %1`.

Comment: You could try checking the value of `kill-emacs-hook` (`C-h v kill-emacs-hook`), and see if any of the functions in that list look like they could be doing this.

Comment: If the hint of elethan does not help you could activate the option `Enter Debugger on Error` in the `Options` menu. It produces a stacktrace in the error case. Maybe, you can fix your problem with the help of this stacktrace. If you cannot get rid of the problem paste the stacktrace here.

Answer (score 1):

With the suggestions of @elethan and @Tobias I was able to generate this stack-trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp "make -k ")
  savehist-save(t)
  savehist-autosave()
  kill-emacs()
  save-buffers-kill-emacs(nil)   
  save-buffers-kill-terminal(nil)
  call-interactively(save-buffers-kill-terminal nil nil)
```

And track it down to savehist, which I disabled for now.